# How to use custom url in ransack's sort link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

So, I have a nested route which also takes some custom parameters. In the index action I've setup ransacker with @q as the query parameter, but in the views when I am not able to use `sort_link` , because I can't find a way to pass the custom url, as in `search_form_for`... So do you know any way to do this?